# Not able to upload file using PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I am pretty new to AJAX and I am stuck with this problem of not being able to upload files to desired folder. The upload seems fine but the file do not appear in `F:/xampp/htdocs/pgadmsn/uploads/`. Maybe I am missing something minute, please help me out.

uf.html:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Select a File to Upload</label> <input id="fileToUpload1" type="file" name="fileToUpload1" /> 
    <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="loadFile()" />
</form>
<script>
function loadFile() {
    var myFileList = document.getElementById('fileToUpload1').files;
    var fileToUpload = myFileList[0];
    alert(fileToUpload.name);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'http://10.192.44.143/pgadmsn/upload.php');
    xhr.send(fileToUpload);
}
</script>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "F:/xampp/htdocs/pgadmsn/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need a webserver to use AJAX. If you're using a webserver then paths with drive letters like `F:\....` are not available to you as you need URL's.

Comment: I changed it to ' http://10.192.44.143/pgadmsn/uploads/ ' ;didn't help!

Comment: use relative path from your script location to the folder where you want to save the file.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim didn't work!

Comment: @JayBlanchard Do u mean console? Yeah, I checked that.

Comment: No, the PHP error logs.

Comment: I checked. It says that "Undefined index: fileToUpload in F:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pgadmsn\\upload.php on line 3" Detail: .....[Fri Jun 24 02:13:42.257848 2016] [:error] [pid 3984:tid 1796] [client 10.192.44.143:60190] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: fileToUpload in F:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pgadmsn\\upload.php on line 3, referer: http://10.192.44.143/pgadmsn/uf.html
[Fri Jun 24 02:13:42.258349 2016] [:error] [pid 3984:tid 1796] [client 10.192.44.143:60190] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: fileToUpload in F:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pgadmsn\\upload.php on line 23, referer: http://10.192.44.143/pgadmsn/uf.html

Comment: There you go - all you have to do is fix that and you'll be in business.

Comment: @AnkitShubham In your HTML code, the upload field name is `fileToUpload1` but in your PHP code you are trying with `fileToUpload`. Please fix it.

Comment: I think that when XMLHttpRequest() sends fileToUpload as 'xhr.send(fileToUpload)' , the php script is not able to detect it or something like that. Hence the undefined error.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim I think its correct.